# Vert.x. How to create a real polyglot JVM application?

Tags: java, ruby, jvm, kotlin, vert.x

I'm inspecting [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/), a framework that can run an application in several different JVM languages.

There are a huge number of examples available at [vertx-examples](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples).

But the problem is, (and I didn't find anything yet) how could we write a Vert.x application on a real polyglot way (using all supported JVM languages at the same time)?

For example, how can we write a code that uses the following files:
`Java.java`, `Kotlin.kt`, `Javascript.js`, `Ruby.rb`.
Where each one have a simple function inside of it that print the language name (for example the Ruby.rb prints `ruby`).

For example, when using this input:

`$vertx run Polyglot.java`

how can we achieve the following output?

`java, kotlin, javascript, ruby`

**Edit**, my attempt:

**Polyglot.java**

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Launcher;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class Polyglot extends AbstractVerticle {

  public static void main(args: String[]) {
    Launcher.main(new String[] { "run", Polyglot.class.getName(), "-ha"});
  }

  @Override
  public void start() {

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(req -> {
      final String name = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
      req.response().end(
        Java.message()
        + Kotlin.message()
      );
    }).listen(8080);
  }
}
```

**Java.java**

```
public class Java {

    public static String message() {
        return "Java\n";
    }
}
```

**Kotlin.kt**

```
class Kotlin {

    companion object {
        fun message() {
            return "Kotlin\n"
        }
    }
}
```

`vertx run Polyglot.java`

Comment: assuming you have tried, which specific roadblock have you hit?

Answer (score 1):

But you can :)

Here's how:

1. Create a verticle in java
2. Create a verticle in JS
3. Create a verticle in Kotlin

Now either run each verticle independently with cluster mode on (so verticles communicate over the eventbus which is a common abstraction across all languages) or create a extra verticle that deploys all verticles in the same JVM and again use the eventbus to do message driven development across languages.

Comment: Hum, so, can't we use the same base code? My final goal about this is to using for example JRuby on Rails and Kotlin with Spring Boot for example. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: It depends. For example you can mix and match to some extent. Say that you have a JS verticle then you can rely on nashorn to do interop with java and since kotlin also can be used from java you can interact with kotlin. I don't mention ruby because I'm do not know the inwards of the engine. Here's an example of JS with Java: http://www.jetdrone.xyz/2017/01/25/Vertx-Polyglot-Proxy-Services.html